# Merging Last column in the gridview according to first column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with the first column merged. I used the following code in databound.

```
 for (int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
 {
     GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
     GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

     for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < gvRow.Cells.Count - 3; cellCount++)   
     {
         if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
         {
             if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
             {
                 gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;                           
             }
             else
             {
                 gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;                           
              }
                    gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
          }
      }
  }
```

I want to merge the last column according to first column.
I tried with the following code. But it did not work.

```
 for (int t = 0; t < GridView1.Rows.Count; t++)
 {
    GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[3].RowSpan = GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[0].RowSpan;            
 }
```

Can anyone help me doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many columns do you have? You probably want to merge the one before the last.

Comment: I have four columnns.First one is merged. And then i want merge the last one.But I want the last column o be merged according to the first column.

Answer (score 1):

As i said in the comment, if you want the 4th row to be merged with the 3rd you should set the merge property on the 3rd column.

```
for (int t = 0; t < GridView1.Rows.Count; t++)
{
   GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].RowSpan = GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[0].RowSpan;            
}
```